# ListView открытие неправильного активти после организации поиска через EditText

Tags: java, android, listview

В общем решил влиться в андроид программирование, прошёл начинающий курс так скажем. На основе одной из программ решил сделать свою. 
В чем соб-на проблема, **нашёл как организовать поиск по listview с помощью editview.** 
**Поиск работает, однако после «фильтрации» сбивается id и открывается не правильный Активити. 
(Например *должен* открыться *хоккей*, а о*ткрывается футбол* тк он первый в обычном списке)** 
Как исправить в моем случае данную проблему? Чтобы id не менялись после поиска. 
Искренне и робко прошу помочь мне не разумному.
Ниже - сам класс с данными о Видах Спорта (Sport.class)

```
public class Sport {
    //Класс содержащий массив с нашими данными
    //-То что хранит в себе каждый "Спорт"
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int imageResourceId;

    private Sport(String name, String description, int imageResourceId){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    }
    //
    public  static  final Sport[] sports = {
            new Sport("Футбол","Спортивная игра двух команд (по одиннадцать игроков в каждой)", R.drawable.football),
            new Sport("Хокке","Командная игра на льду на коньках с использованием шайбы и клюшек", R.drawable.hockey),
            new Sport("Волейбол","Спортивная игра в мяч, перебрасывая мяч через сетку от одной команды к другой", R.drawable.volleyball),
            new Sport("Регби","Спортивная игра с овальным мячом, который игроки передают друг, другу с цельью попасть в ворота", R.drawable.rugby),
            new Sport("Танцы","Ритмичные, выразительные телодвижения обычно выстраиваемые в " +
                    "определенную композицию", R.drawable.dancing),
            new Sport("Баскетбол","Игра в которой мяч забрасывают в подвешенную сетку" +
                    "называемую корзиной", R.drawable.basketball),
            new Sport("Теннис","Спортивная игра маленьким мячом, который перебрасывается ракеткой через сетку", R.drawable.tennis),
            new Sport("Плавание","Вид спорта или спортивная дисциплина, заключающаяся в " +
                    "преодалевании водных преград", R.drawable.swimming),
            new Sport("Карате","Спортивная японская борьба, система самозащиты", R.drawable.karate),
            new Sport("Бокс","Кулачный бой в специальных перчатках, по опредленным правилам", R.drawable.boxing)
    };

    //Методы для обращения(доступа)
    public  String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    public int getImageResourceId(){
        return imageResourceId;
    }

    //
    public String toString(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Активти где открывается сам список видов спорта

```
public class CategorySportActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ArrayAdapter<Sport> listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category_sport);

        //ListView
        ListView listSport = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        //adapter для его работы + откуда берем спиок
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Sport.sports); //Sport.sports - наш массив (список)

        listSport.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        //"поиск"
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                CategorySportActivity.this.listAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
        //"поиск"


        //Нажатие на элемент списка - переход в новую активити
        listSport.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CategorySportActivity.this, SportActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(SportActivity.EXTRA_SPORT, (int) id);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Следующая активти (в зависимости от id берет данные из Sport.class)

```
public class SportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     public static final String EXTRA_SPORT = "sportId";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sport);

        int sportId = (Integer) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_SPORT);
        //получить список Sport
        Sport sport = Sport.sports[sportId];
        //получить картинку
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.sport_image);
        imageView.setImageResource(sport.getImageResourceId());
        imageView.setContentDescription(sport.getName());
        //имя
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.sport_name);
        textView.setText(sport.getName());
        //описание
        TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.sport_description);
        textView1.setText(sport.getDescription());

    }
}
```

Прошу предоставить, кодовое решение проблемы, пч обьяснений могу не понять, совсем новичок.

Answer (score 2):

Ну здесь начать и закончить :)

1. Здесь не принято сразу вот писать ответ в виде полного работающего кода - это как бы такой антипаттерн поведения
2. Здесь принято заставлять топикстартера думать головой, в общем если ждете просто копипаст - то можете дальше не читать

Он решается в 2 приема:

1) В `Intent` надо передать не идентификатор о позицию

```
  intent.putExtra(SportActivity.EXTRA_SPORT, position);
```

2) В принимающей `Activity` надо получить ссылку так:

```
    int position = getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_SPORT);
    Sport sport = Sport.sports[position];
```

**Update**

По хорошему надо конечно же делать через реализацию `id` в классе `Sport`

```
public class Sport {
    private long id;
//blah-blah
}
```

и делать класс

```
class SportAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sport> {
    @Override
    long getItemId(int position) {
         Sport.sports[position].getId();
    }

    //blah-blah
}
```

Comment: насколько я помню, в ArrayAdapter значения position и id из колбэка onItemClick() равны (отличаются только для адаптеров, "понимающих" id, как CursorAdapter). Проблема же как раз в том, что нет идентификаторов вида спорта, по которым их можно различить. массив sports не изменяется после фильтрации и первый там всегда футбол, когда после фильтрации на первой позиции может оказаться, например, хоккей, но по запросу по позиции, из массива мы все равно получим футбол

Comment: вот с реализацией из update в колбэке onItemClick() как раз уже надо посылать через интент отдавемый колбэком id (четвертый параметр), так как при реализации адаптера по вашему примеру он будет возвращать его корректное значение, а не position, как вы писали ранее

Comment: Да, вы правы надо посылать не `position`, а `id`

Comment: @Barmaley подскажите пожалуйста, что еще по мимо getItemId метода в SportAdapter нужно добавлять, я пока не сталкивался с искусственным Адаптером, посмотрел по примерам в Интернете, не могу понять что конкретно нужно еще сделать. В Category получилось таким образом - ArrayList<Sport> myList = new ArrayList<>(); listAdapter = new SportAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList); В онКликСлушател добавил переменную получающую Id из вашего метода. Однако, список не выводит.  (писал под записью ниже мб вы не заметили)

Answer (score 0):

В общем для тех кто встретится с данной проблемой в будущем. 
Ответ @Barmaley заставил задуматься о *"позиции"*, поискав в интернете получилось решить проблему следующим способом...

Вместо Id **теперь intent-ом отправляем "Имя" спорта** в следующую активити.

(*String name = listSport.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();* - консоль сообщила что команда возвращает\получает *название категории спорта элемента* (**"Футбол", "Хоккей", "Волейбол"...**) списка listSport)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
 //Нажатие на элемент списка - переход в новую активити
        listSport.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CategorySportActivity.this, SportActivity.class);
                String name = listSport.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();//получаю "Имя" в списке
                intent.putExtra(SportActivity.EXTRA_SPORT, name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

А следующей активти действовал следующим образом.

```js
 public static final String EXTRA_SPORT = "sportId";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sport);

        String sport_name = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_SPORT); //получаю "имя"
        //в зависимости от имени получаю картинку, имя, описание
        //id (соответсвует списку Sport)
        int id = 0;
        if (sport_name.equals("Футбол")){
            id = 0;

        }
        if (sport_name.equals("Хокке")) {
            id = 1;

        }
        if (sport_name.equals("Волейбол")){
            id = 2;
        }
        //.....

        //получить список Sport
        Sport sport = Sport.sports[id];
        //получить картинку
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.sport_image);
        imageView.setImageResource(sport.getImageResourceId());
        imageView.setContentDescription(sport.getName());
        //имя
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.sport_name);
        textView.setText(sport.getName());
        //описание
        TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.sport_description);
        textView1.setText(sport.getDescription());

    }
}
```

Теперь при поиске никаких проблем с открытием правильной активити нет.

Comment: правильно будет добавить поле (переменную) с этим id (по факту порядковый номер в массиве Sports) в модель Sport,при клике получать его вместо имени и передавать во вторую активити, а не "вычислять" этот id из имени через кучу if во второй активити (представьте, что у вас будет 500 этих категорий, писать столько if-ов надо нанимать эникейщика отдельно, программисты слишком ленивые для этого, потому работают головой, а не руками)

Comment: Это плохое решение. Я в своем ответе сначала начинал описывать ответ через реализацию `id`, но подумав было решил, что для начинающего это не очень верно, теперь вижу что был неправ - все таки надо решать через `id`

Comment: см. апдейт. А делать привязку через контент - это как бы довольно токсичная идея - а если надо будет перевести на арабский - тогда как?

Comment: @Barmaley что еще по мимо getItemId метода в SportAdapter нужно добавлять, я пока не сталкивался с искусственным Адаптером, посмотрел по примерам в Интернете, не могу понять что конкретно нужно еще сделать.                                                                                            В Category получилось таким образом - ArrayList<Sport> myList = new ArrayList<>();              listAdapter = new SportAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);                              В онКликСлушател добавил переменную получающую Id из вашего метода. Однако, список не выводит.